# How to uphold ties with non mahram relatives like first cousins ? Is it allowed talk with them freely and please tell the islamic guidelines to talk

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, fiqh, prophet-muhammad, sunnah

What are the islamic guidelines while talking to non mahram relatives like first cousins. In my family they touch each other and does not lower their gaze and talk freely.please advice the way prophet Muhammad peace upon him